# ASP.NET 4.8 Azure DevOps YAML build error

Tags: asp.net, azure, yaml, devops

For over few days I am struggling to create a simple build of ASP.NET 4.8 MVC application (simple one, straight from project examples as we are creating new project).

Edit: here is link to whole solution: https://github.com/roofiq/asp.net-4.8-mvc
Firstly I was trying to figure it out on my own, then decided to use example starte pipeline, that should do the job. As below:

```
variables:
  solution: 'web-mvc.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Here is my folder structure:
Repository:

```
 - build.yml - yaml template that contains above code
 - web-mvc.sln
 - web-mvc - folder
   - packages.config
   - web-mvc.csproj
   - etc..other files and folder that consist of this solution
```

Looks simple, right. When I run it, I'm getting the following error when build task is trying to copy files to artifact directory.

```
2020-11-06T13:53:18.5214254Z   Copying Content\bootstrap.min.css.map to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Content\bootstrap.min.css.map.
2020-11-06T13:53:18.5823318Z ##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2601,5): Error : Copying file Content\bootstrap.min.css.map to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Content\bootstrap.min.css.map failed. Could not find file 'Content\bootstrap.min.css.map'.
2020-11-06T13:53:18.5927156Z C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(2601,5): error : Copying file Content\bootstrap.min.css.map to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\Content\bootstrap.min.css.map failed. Could not find file 'Content\bootstrap.min.css.map'. [D:\a\1\s\web-mvc\web-mvc.csproj]
2020-11-06T13:53:18.5936582Z Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\web-mvc\web-mvc.csproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
2020-11-06T13:53:18.6126516Z Done Building Project "D:\a\1\s\web-mvc.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.
2020-11-06T13:53:18.6177112Z 
2020-11-06T13:53:18.6177941Z Build FAILED.
```

In previous logs, it has successfully copied other files that were in `Content` folder.
I had no issues with building .Net core apps, but with this one it's really hard to follow up. I was using `nuget.config` and tried to build by `csproj` file. But failing each time.

Could you suggest me some adjustments? What is the best approach?

Thanks,
Rafal

Comment: Is there a way you can share your solution with me?

Comment: Hey @RameshKanjinghat, I have uploaded solution to github, here is the link: [https://github.com/roofiq/asp.net-4.8-mvc](https://github.com/roofiq/asp.net-4.8-mvc).

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't recreate the issue. I was able to run the pipeline multiple times. [https://github.com/rameshkanjinghat/asp.net-4.8-mvc/blob/main/Pipeline-Success-Screenshot.jpg]. This is the screenshot for your reference. I see that you are running this on your local agent. Did you try to restart the machine where your agent is running?

Comment: Thanks for checking it out @RameshKanjinghat. Well, it is running on Azure DevOps agents and they are restarted on every run so it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Any updates on this? having same issues as this. Thanks in advance